# sql query convert to mongodb

Tags: mongodb

how convert follow mysql query to mongodb query:

```
INSERT INTO `users` SELECT `username`,`password` from `old_user`;
```

and atomic query

Answer (score 2):

Following will be the query in MongoDB:-

```
db.old_user.find({},{username:1,password:1}).forEach(function(data){                                                                                       
db.users.insert(data)                                                                                                                                
})
```

Comment: this query is atomic on mongodb?

Comment: @javadshariaty no it isn't.